# DOM Exception 19 for PUT request

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest, put

I'm making a PUT request to upload an object to S3 bucket using xmlhttprequest in Javascript. The CORS are set properly. This is the code which I'm trying with.

```
        var bucketPath = 'http://<bucket-name>.s3.amazon.com/'
        var fileName = <name> + ".json";
        var uploadPath = bucketPath + fileName.replace(/\s/g,"+");
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                showData();
            }
            else{
                showError();
            }
          };
        xmlhttp.open("PUT",uploadPath,false);
        xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(jsonObject), replacer);
```

I get a DOM Exception 19 at the last line of code. Not sure what is wrong. I tried doing the same with a sample test script and it works. Only when I try to use it for my application altogether, it is throwing this exception.

In Network Tab under Chrome debugger, I can see a HTTP request with Method as OPTIONS and Type as pending.

I couldn't see the actual PUT request being sent. Can anyone tell me what the problem is and what the Exception meant?

Update:
After carefully looking the requests being sent from jsfiddle and my application. I see 2 requests being sent from JS Fiddle a preflight HTTP OPTIONS request and after that the actual PUT request.

While it works great on JS fiddle, on the otherhand the same code from my applications sends a preflight HTTP OPTIONS request but doesn't get a 200 back the status is pending. That is the reason why it is failing.

Any ideas why I'm not getting success for HTTP OPTIONS request.

Comment: I see nowhere that CORS is being used...

Comment: I meant. I've already set up the CORS rule for my S3 bucket to allow PUT request from my website

Comment: But the browser doesn't know that. I believe you need to use something like this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: Can you give me an example? and also does it mean it works only in IE?

Comment: There is nothing special you need to do client side when sending a cross origin request.  The user agent handles any preflighting.  The server is expected to be aware of and specifically deal with cross origin requests, not the client (you. In this case).  If you have setup your CORS rules on your S3 bucket, there is nothing more you need to do, unless you intend to make a credentialed request, which doesn't apply when dealing with S3 as far as I know.  The error you are seeing is apparently some network issue.  Can you describe the differences between your "test script" and this one?

Comment: Also, if you want to upload a file to S3 via your browser directly, why aren't you using the wel l documented "upload via HTML form" approach instead? You can find this described in great deal on the AWS developer site.

Comment: Reason I'm not doing without form is, I want it to happen automatically without any user interaction. And I couldn't see any difference from the test script to my script.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nHa74/ is the code of my test script which is working. I've removed the bucket name, though.

Comment: Why aren't you using your test script code in production?  Also, It's almost always a bad idea to send synchronous ajax requests.  If you have to do this, most likely your application is not designed properly.

Comment: No I tried that. Both the things are erroring out, in my production. And I take your word about sync requests but that is a flag I changed to see if it has any effect, turns out it doesn't

Comment: If you aren't getting a response to the preflight, then there is some network issue on your production environment (perhaps something is intercepting the request) or your CORS configuration in S3 is incorrect.  Hard to say, could be many things.  You'll need to spend some more time looking at the request, your code, and your envionment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got the bug. Nothing to do with CORS. The url which I'm trying to do a PUT request should be  http://bucket-name.s3.amazon**aws**.com/